# Filtering table from another table in vaadin

Tags: filtering, vaadin

I was wondering how to filter one table based on what I click on in another table.  For example if I click on Russia in the country table it should filter all the people from Russia in the name table.  I would like to know how to do this using vaadin.  I added some relevant code below.  The country table is suppose to filter the name table when I click on a country.

Here is my filter method:

```
public class CountryFilter implements Filter {
    public String needle;
    public CountryFilter(String needle) {
        this.needle = needle;
    }

    public boolean appliesToProperty(Object id) {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean passesFilter(Object itemId, Item item) {
        String haystack = ("" + item.getItemProperty(Name) +
                                item.getItemProperty(Country)).toLowerCase();
        return haystack.contains(needle);
    }
}
```

Here is my search method that uses the filter

```
    public void initCountrySearch() {   
    country.setSelectable(true);
    country.setImmediate(true);
    name.setVisibleColumns(new String[] {"name"});
    country.setVisibleColumns(new String[] {"country"});


country.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            data.name.removeAllContainerFilters();
            data.name.addContainerFilter(new CountryFilter(event.getProperty().getValue().toString()));
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: can you add your Exception, which you get?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a ValueChangeListener on your selection criteria table which informs you about, well, a value change. In the value change method you can get the selected item and according to this item you do a loading on your target table.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, for the selection I added a listener to listen for any selection made.  I am having trouble filtering the other table based on this selection.

Comment: @abden003 what makes you trouble? Could you give us more details, like sample codes?

Comment: I added a listener so that it filters the other table when I select something (I created my own filter class) the problem I have now is that the filter takes in a String and the listener (Property.ValueChangeListener) takes in a property, and whenever I use toString or try to convert the property to a string I get an error message saying that it is not supported in vaadin